# Change the URL of a KML file that Google Maps references on button click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to initially display an 8 Day Average KML file in Google Maps on first page load, but allow the user to click the "1 Day" and "3 Day" button to have Google Maps reference those instead of the "8 Day".

The goal is to create a mini template for users to add three sets of values for the H3 header text, the URL for the KML file to reference in Google Maps as well as the HREF URL in the "Download KML" link below the map for several pages that will display satellite imagery for various locations in the world.

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the values depending on what HTML button the user presses.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>KML Swapperooni Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&signed_in=false"></script>
   
   <h2>MARACOOS Sea Surface Temperature</h2>
   <h3 id="HeaderText">8 Day Average Delaware Bay Sea Surface Temperature</h3>
   
   <div>
    <button type="button" value="1Day">1 Day Average</button>
    <button type="button" value="3Day">3 Day Average</button>
    <button type="button" value="8Day" autofocus>8 Day Average</button>
   </div>

   <div id="map-canvas" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 600px;">&nbsp;</div>
   
   <p><a id="kmlLink" href='http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/public_kmls/MARACOOS_SST/Delaware_8_Day_Sea_Surface_Temperature_Current.kml'>Download KML</a></p>
   
   <script>
    // var 1Day.HeaderText = "1 Day Average Delaware Bay Sea Surface Temperature"
    // var 1Day.kmlURL = "http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/public_kmls/MARACOOS_SST/Delaware_1_Day_Sea_Surface_Temperature_Current.kml"
    // var 3Day.HeaderText = "3 Day Average Delaware Bay Sea Surface Temperature"
    // var 3Day.kmlURL = "http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/public_kmls/MARACOOS_SST/Delaware_3_Day_Sea_Surface_Temperature_Current.kml"
    // var 8Day.HeaderText = "8 Day Average Delaware Bay Sea Surface Temperature"
    // var 8Day.kmlURL = "http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/public_kmls/MARACOOS_SST/Delaware_8_Day_Sea_Surface_Temperature_Current.kml"
    
   function initialize() {
     var mapcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(38.787324, -75.162954);
     var kmlURL = 'http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/public_kmls/MARACOOS_SST/Delaware_8_Day_Sea_Surface_Temperature_Current.kml'
     var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 11,
       center: mapcenter,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
     }
   
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   
     var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
       url: kmlURL});
     ctaLayer.setMap(map);
   }
   
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   
   </script>
    
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manipulated your data a a bit to be more generic.

You have to declare map and ctalayers as global objects, load the new KML URL and render it to the map as:

```
ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: kmlURL});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

**Full demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Rsp22/2209/

Answer (score 0):

Is easy you can load the three different KML in three separated ctaLayer eg ctaLayer1, ctaLayer3, ctaLayer8 
and then with with different button invoke a onclick event for  call related different function setting  the correspondant  ctaLayer. 
A ctaLayer is set to map and the other to null  eg

```
  ctaLayer3.setMap(map);
  ctaLayer1.setMap(null); 
  ctaLayer8.setMap(null);
```